# "Small" zero divisors in $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z]$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, fourier-transform, group-algebras

If $p$ is a prime, and $a,b$ are non-zero elements of the group algebra $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z]$ satisfying $a\ast b=0$, then $$|{\rm supp}\ a|+|{\rm supp}\ b|\ge p+2.$$ This is easy to prove using characters, but is there a reasonably simple elementary proof? Does this fact have a standard name / reference? Is it somehow related to the Cauchy-Davenport theorem? How does it extend onto the group algebras $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z]$ with $m$ composite?

Comment: I guess that $\mathbf{Z}_n$ denotes the cyclic group (not the $n$-adics), but you could have said it.

Comment: @YCor: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ <---- $\mathbb{Z}/p$. Done.

Comment: @Qfwfq I don't like the notation $\mathbf{Z}_m$ for the cyclic group of order $m$ but it's quite common in combinatorics, so I wouldn't have modified the post without the OP's authorization.

Comment: @YCor: it's quite common also in topology. But I belong to the Army Against the Confusion of Notation Between Cyclics and p-Adics :)

Comment: Well if you're going to change it (I prefer ${\bf Z}_p$; the confusion arises because $p$-adicists insist on using this notation), at least let it make sense: ${\bf Z}/p{\bf Z}$, not  ${\bf Z}/p$.

Comment: for composite $m$ there are problems, say, $(g^5-1)(g^5+1)=0$ for a generator $g$ of the cyclic group of order 10.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: right, one should not expect the assertion to hold literally for $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z]$; the subgroup structure should be somehow involved. Say, in your example ${\rm supp}\ a={\rm supp}\ b$ is the two-element subgroup.

Comment: Do you want to assume that $a$ and $b$ are non-zero? As it stands, $a=b=0$ is a counterexample to your statement.

Comment: @David Handelman: either $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is fine for me; just, the former makes more sense but it's a bit heavier.

Comment: At the first glance, this could follow from the following claim: If $A,B\subset \mathbb Z_p$ are such that for every $c\in A+B$ there are at least two pairs $(a,b)\in A\times B$ with $a+b=c$, then $|A|+|B|\geq p+2$. But this claim is false. As a counterexample, take $p=23$, $A=\{1,2,\dots,6\}$, $B=\{1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22\}$.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: The question of how small must $A,B\subset\mathbb F_p$ be to ensure that $A+B$ contains a uniquely representable elements has been intensively studied, and there are examples of logarithmic-size sets not having this unique representation property.

Comment: I see how this result follows from Tao's "An uncertainty principle for cyclic groups of prime order" (which does mention Cauchy-Davenport), but what is the "easy" proof with characters?

Comment: @MTyson: 
$\newcommand{\supp}{\mathrm{supp}\,}$
I guess the argument you found is exactly what I had in mind ($\hat a\cdot\hat b=0$ implying $|\supp\hat a|+|\supp\hat b|\le p$, while $|\supp\hat a|\ge p+1-|\supp a|$ and $|\supp\hat b|\ge p+1-|\supp b|$).